# Is it possible to maintain a same git project on two different remotes (private and public) with different commit history?

Tags: git, github

I have been working on a private repository, where the project has initially been created with some sensible data. Now that I have enough content on the project I'd like to make it public on Github.

The work is still on-going and I'd like to avoid to maintain two different repositories.

The idea would be to have
[image]

From `commit 29` everything would remain in sync (private and public).

### From what I've read

This seems to be impossible based on the way Git works (cf. [Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243201/3708721))

### But

Could it be possible to fiddle around with the git hooks from my private repository to push to github ?

#### SO references

[Managing a private and public remote with different histories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156559/managing-a-private-and-public-remote-with-different-histories)
[Import existing source code to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658606/import-existing-source-code-to-github/8012698#8012698)
[Resetting remote to a certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816688/resetting-remote-to-a-certain-commit/5816761#5816761)
[Maintain a private and a public repo simultaneously using git branch with two different clouds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353168/maintain-a-private-and-a-public-repo-simultaneously-using-git-branch-with-two-di)
[GitHub: How to make a fork of public repository private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065526/github-how-to-make-a-fork-of-public-repository-private/30352360#30352360)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an orphaned branch to achieve this:

```
# Suppose the tip of master has everything you want to start out as
# the initial commit in github
git checkout master
git remote add github <url to the project>
git checkout --orphan public
git push --set-upstream github public
```

Now effectively you have two repos in your local repo, pointed to by `public` and `master`. They are unrelated, so you won't be able to `merge` either way. You can copy commits between them using `cherry-pick` or patches however.

If you wish to continue to use `master` for future development, simply do:

```
git checkout master
git branch master-archived
git reset --hard public
```

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed the job, I'll valid your answer. Have a nice day.